# How to express nested array in expectJSONTypes in frisby?

Tags: arrays, frisby.js

For example, I've got a response like this:

```
{
  "name": "David",
  "age": 45,
  "company": [
    {
      "name": "G00g1e",
      "id": 253674,
      "employee": [
        {
          "name": "Frank",
          "age": 20
        },
        {
          "name": "Jason",
          "age": 21
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "F4ceb00k",
      "id": 937394,
      "employee": [
        {
          "name": "James",
          "age": 20
        },
        {
          "name": "Zuck",
          "age": 23
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and here is the frisby expectJSONTypes statements:

```
// assertion success
    .expectJSONTypes({
        name: String,
        age: Number,
        company: Array
    })
// assertion success
    .expectJSONTypes('company.*', {
        name: String,
        id: Number,
        employee: Array
    })
// TypeError: Expected 'company.employee.*' to be Array (got 'undefined' from JSON response)
    .expectJSONTypes('company.employee.*', {
        name: String,
        age: Number
    })
```

It seems correct to express the nested array like this according to my understanding, but actually it doesn't work. How to modify the third expectJSONTypes statement to express this kind of situation correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to test the first element of the array:

```
.expectJSONTypes('company.0', {
    name: String,
    id: Number,
    employee: Array
})
```